# Installation not initialized

Tags: boot, system-installation, samsung

I recently got a Samsung Galaxy Book Go, which has a Qualcomm Snapdragon 7c Gen 2 processor, I'm trying to install Ubuntu, but it doesn't load the system installation screen.

Security boot is disabled.

Does anyone have a tip on how to resolve this?

Comment: What image you are trying to boot?

Comment: Ubuntu Server ARM 22.04 LTS

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)